# Garbage collection: object properties

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an object that contains another objects as its properties like

```
var obj = {
    '1': {...},
    '42': {...}
};
```

When `obj` gets out of scope - do all nested objects destroyed implicitly or I need to iterate over them and `delete` explicitly?

Comment: Assuming that nothing else had a handle to `obj` or any of those properties, they should get picked up by the GC eventually. The usual approach is to set things to `null` rather than deleting them. Use special care when dealing with DOM nodes, references to them can hang around, especially in "certian browsers." Pay extra special care to circular references involving DOM objects (foo = document.body; document.body['data-blah'] = foo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, unless another reference still exists :

```
var obj = {
    '1': {...},
    '42': {...}
};


var save = obj['1'];

obj = null;
```

After garbage collection and assuming no other references have been created then the space for obj and obj['42'] would be recovered, the value of saved would of course be preserved.

Mea culpa : as mentioned in the comments `delete obj` in my original is not valid since `obj` was declared as a `var`. Had `obj` been a global and hence a property of the global object, `delete` would have worked fine. To effectivly delete a var, use `obj = null`. 
One thing I learned testing this was that `delete` an operator and returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: Yep, there is nothing that refers to nested objects. Thank you

Comment: would the behaviour be the same if instead of `delete obj;` I use `obj = {};` ?

Comment: Nearly in that assigning a new value to obj will remove the reference to the literal but it creates a new literal. Assigning it the value `undefined` is better since it doesn't involve creating a new object just to remove the reference to an old one.

Comment: I don't believe `var objectFoo = {}; delete objectFoo;` is valid (although, yes, I believe there was a certain famous book on javascript that used it that way).  `delete` is used to remove properties from objects, not variables from scope.  But Hans B PUFAL's (and chuckj's) point is still valid. setting `obj = null;` or `obj = whatever;` essentially does the same thing; that is, remove reference to the object instance that was assigned to the `obj` variable.

Comment: @JayC: indeed it is not valid and I asked if I use `= {}` *instead of* `delete`. Well, thanks for that