# JS Garbage collection: Reference to object properties cause whole object to remain on Memory?

Tags: javascript, ajax, object, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

This answer seem to be related, but I need more specific information: [Garbage collection: object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610964/garbage-collection-object-properties)

Suppose I have a global object:

```
var myObj  {
  'some prop' : null
};
```

and an Ajax call (simplified for sake of patience) that return a result:

```
result = {
  prop1 : someObj,
  prop2 : otherObj
}
```

Consider this operation:

```
ajax.get('some url', function(result){
  myObj['some prop'] = results.prop2
});
```

Since objects are assigned by reference, not copied like primitives, I am concerned that the whole `results` object will remain in memory because my global object `myObj` now has a reference to one of its properties (`prop2`).

I suppose this can become a source of data leaks if I run too many Ajax requests.

I don't need all the results, just some properties. Should I have the extra work of deleting unwanted properties from results or cloning result properties instead of assigning?

I wonder if browser garbage collectors are smart enough to deal with this, and/or this is not really a problem.

Comment: I dont think entire `result` will be stored. A nested object is a map of reference. So if you assign some inner object, that should not keep the whole map. But this is just a guess and I'm not sure

Answer (score 3):

Because function parameter represents its local variable, after execution goes out of your Ajax function's scope, `result` object will become effectively useless and could be freed.

But there are some exceptions, like with circular references:

```
function f() {
  var o = {};
  var o2 = {};
  o.a = o2; // o references o2
  o2.a = o; // o2 references o

  return 'azerty';
}
```

Because of **Mark-and-sweep algorithm** the above code would release `o` and `o2` to Garbage Collection, unless you declare one of them in function's outer scope and it could be reached from the Global Scope, so it becomes reachable by the garbage collector (so considered as a needed object, so not removed from the memory).

[SOURCE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management)

Comment: `results` can be deleted, but if you do that, `myObj['some prop'] = results.prop2` will be `myObj['some prop'] = null` after that because it is a reference. Instead the fact that `results.prop2` is still accessible from  `myObj['some prop']` makes me think that `results.prop1` is also lingering in memory. *That's* the big problem. If `results.prop1` is a large object and I am ignoring it, I might have problems after many calls. So I either do `delete results.prop1` or `myObj['some prop'] = _.clone(results.prop2); delete results;` *I suppose*.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I was planing to delete this post. Just to note - you better do `_.cloneDeep`, because `.clone` juts creates a shallow clone of the value, so AFAIK it doesn't differ so much from the usual reference (but I must investigate this difference more, though)

Comment: Don't delete as it adds information to the topic. 